# SQL Query to pull the required data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application that generates a temporary DeletedList table with call id's.

In my DB I have two tables:

- Table 'Calls' having Call Id and User Id.
- Table 'Users' having user-id and other user details.

I wanted to retrieve all the user-id's such that *all* their call-ids are present in the DeletedList table.

In other words, the query I'm after should *not* contain those user-ids where at least one call is not in the DeletedList table.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Please start over and tag only one of them!

Comment: Though all the products are not involved, the query is related to ANSI SQL and that is the reason why i have tagged all popular RDBMS. Anyways I have removed few.

Comment: Much better. The SQL tag itself is supposed to be used for ANSI SQL!

Comment: There is not a question here, just some requirements. SO is not a code writing service; what have you tried, what caused problems? Have you got some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for *all* the UserIds (i.e., also those with *no calls at all, either deleted or not*), or only the UserIds that have calls, but all of them are deleted?

Comment: Hi Iserni, Thanks for the response, it would be helpful if you can give for also those with no calls at all, either deleted or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the response in two steps one is to select the Id's and delete if they are having any active calls in Table. 
INSERT #Callers
SELECT u.UserId ,u.UserName
                FROM Users u
                JOIN Calls c ON u.Id = c.CallerId
                JOIN DeletedList A ON A.CallId = c.Call_Id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT u.UserId 
                FROM Users u
                LEFT JOIN Calls ON u.Id = c.CallerId
                        GROUP BY u.Id HAVING COUNT(c.Call_Id)=0)SS

DELETE m 
    FROM #Callers m
    JOIN Calls c
        ON c.CallerId = m.UserId 
Though this is working good, can anyone optimize this to single query?

Answer (score 0):

try this query i hope you understand by reading Tables name only
CallerID Table | UserID Table | UserDetails Table
based on that i written a query below
`create procedure proc_getuserdetailsaCallID()
 as begin
Select ud.username from Userdetails ud inner join UserID usid on usid.userid=ud.userid inner join CallerID cid on cid.callerid=usid.callerid
 end`

Comment: Hi Sri, Thanks for the query, but userId and userDetails are in same table 'Users'. We are dealing with three tables 'Calls', 'Users' & 'DeletedList'.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me column names of this 3 table, so i can get clear idea

Comment: Columns in the tables: Table 'DeletedList' - 'Call_Ids'. Table 'Calls' -'Call_Ids' ,'User_Id'. Table 'Users' - 'User_id', 'User_name'

Comment: you can see in that query i used 3 tables to get data based on callerid, i hope the above query gives some idea for you how to achieve